# A general inequality for KL divergence of functions of variables

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, it.information-theory

The question concerns a very general setting and a very general inequality about KL divergence. I'm writing this thread to verify whether my intuition is correct.

Let $E_1, E_2$ be two measurable spaces, $f, g: E_1 \rightarrow E_2$ two measurable functions, and $A, B$ two random variables taking values in $E_1$. Is the following inequality:

$D_{KL}(f(A) || g(B)) \le D_{KL}(A || B)$

always true?

In case it isn't, I'd like to ask whether the following inequality is always true:

$D_{KL}(f(A) || f(B)) \le D_{KL}(A || B)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\si}{\sigma}\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal F}\newcommand{\G}{\mathcal G}\newcommand{\pa}{\parallel}$The first inequality is obviously false in general, e.g. when $A=B$ but $f(A)$ differs from $g(B)=g(A)$ in distribution.

The second inequality is true. A bit more generally, let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be probability measures defined on a $\si$-algebra $\F$. Let $\mu_\G$ and $\nu_\G$ be the restrictions of $\mu$ and $\nu$ to a sub-$\si$-algebra $\G$ of $\F$.

> Then
> \begin{equation*}
>     D_{KL}(\mu_\G\pa\nu_\G)\le D_{KL}(\mu\pa\nu). \tag{1}\label{1}
> \end{equation*}

Indeed,
\begin{equation*}
    D_{KL}(\mu\pa\nu)=\int d\nu\,h\Big(\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}\Big),
\end{equation*}
where $h(u):=u\ln u$ for $u\in(0,\infty)$, with $h(0):=0$ and $h(\infty)=\infty$.
Next, letting $E_\nu(\cdot|\G)$ denote the conditional expectation given $\G$ w.r.t. $\nu$, for any nonnegative $\G$-measurable function $q$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    \int d\nu_\G\,q\, E_\nu\Big(\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}\Big|\G\Big)
    =   \int d\nu\,q\, E_\nu\Big(\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}\Big|\G\Big)\, 
    =\int d\nu\,q\, \frac{d\mu}{d\nu}\, 
    =   \int d\mu\,q=   \int d\mu_\G\,q; 
\end{equation*}
the second equality in the latter display holds by the definition of the conditional expectation. So,
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{d\mu_\G}{d\nu_\G}=E_\nu\Big(\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}\Big|\G\Big). 
\end{equation*}
So, by Jensen's inequality applied to the convex function $h$,
\begin{multline*}
    D_{KL}(\mu_\G\pa\nu_\G)
    =\int d\nu\,h\Big(\frac{d\mu_\G}{d\nu_\G}\Big)
        =\int d\nu\,h\Big(E_\nu\Big(\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}\Big|\G\Big)\Big) \\ 
    \le \int d\nu\,E_\nu\Big( h\Big(\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}\Big)\Big|\G\Big)
    =\int d\nu\,h\Big(\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}\Big) 
    =D_{KL}(\mu\pa\nu), 
\end{multline*}
so that \eqref{1} follows.

Your second inequality now obtains by letting $\mu$ and $\nu$ be the distributions of $A$ and $B$, respectively, over the measurable space $(E_1,\F)$ and letting $\G$ be the sub-$\si$-algebra of $\F$ generated by the measurable map $f$.
$\quad\Box$

Answer (score 2):

The second inequality is typically called the "data-processing inequality". You can look up precise conditions on $f$ such that it is true (measurability suffices, but you may even assume it is a randomized transformation, typically called a "markov kernel" iirc).

The first inequality is not always true. Consider $A, B\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$ independently.
Let $f(x) = x+\mu$, and $g(x) = x$.
Then $D_{KL}(A||B) = 0$, but $D_{KL}(f(A)||g(B)) \neq 0$, so the inequality cannot hold.